# Catching exceptions doesn't work

Tags: c#, exception

I'm having some trouble catching exceptions:

```
private static void WriteLog(string line, string currentDirectory, string dataLocation, int retries)
{
    string localPath = currentDirectory + dataLocation;
    // Write CSV header if the log file does not yet exist
    bool writeHeader = !File.Exists(localPath);
    try
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(localPath))
        {
            LogMessage("Log file opened. Writing...");
            if (writeHeader)
                sw.WriteLine(csvHeader);
            sw.WriteLine(line);
            sw.Close();
            LogMessage("Wrote line successfully. Log file closing.");
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        if (++retries > 3) return;
        LogMessage($"Cannot write to file because it is open. Retrying.. {retries}/3 (Exception: {e.Message})");
        var retryDuration = TimeSpan.FromTicks(ApplicationSettings.AnalysisInterval.Ticks / 3);
        Thread.Sleep(retryDuration);
        WriteLog(line, currentDirectory, dataLocation, retries);
    }
    LogMessage($"Logged line after {retries} retries.");
    Task.Run(() => DropboxUploader.UploadCsv(localPath, dataLocation));
}
```

StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(localPath) is the line throwing an IOException. As you can see, I try to catch it using a try/catch block, but the IOException is still being thrown. This also seems to happen with other exceptions. Does anybody know why the exception still gets thrown?

Comment: Click debug > windows > exception settings & look at the value for CLR exceptions

Comment: you checked if it was there  - not if you could write to it. Plus if you run it in debug often exceptions still show - whats the action IO exception..

Comment: problem occured because of "using". Try to catch exception not ioexception

Comment: i think this is what happens - you fail writing three times. then after returning the thrid try - your second try - logs "logged after 2 tries" and your exception is coming from UploadCsv - since the file was not there or not accessible.

insert a return after the writelog-recursion.

Comment: Add  catch (Exception ex){  } and check what is the actual reason for the exception. There may be some other reason for the exception.

Comment: IOException is the base class for many more specialized exceptions. As always, post the full error messages and (top of) the stack trace.

Comment: But your structure is needlessly complicated. Do not use recursion and exceptions to create a retry-loop. Use a `while(iter < limit)` and `break` on success.

Comment: Additional problem with recursion: the last 2 lines of the method will be executed as many time as many retries.

Answer (score 0):

All IOExceptions thrown in the try-clause will be caught in the catch-clause. 
Either it's NOT an IOException that is being thrown, perhaps it's only an Exception?

Or if it's an IOException that is being thrown it originates from things happening after the try clause.

Eg. I notice you try log stuff both in the catch clause and after the try-catch clause. I guess you write data to a file and that will most certanly throw an IOException if something goes wrong